# Unable find package linux-header-3.2.46

Tags: kernel, package-management

Linux-header package is not installed.

```
root@pc-4:~# apt-cache policy linux-headers-3.2.46
N: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.2.46'
root@pc-4:~#
root@pc-4:~#

Unable to install packages

root@pc-4:~# apt-get install linux-headers-3.2.46
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.2.46
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.2.46'

root@pc-4:~# uname -r
3.2.46
root@pc-4:~# uname -a
Linux pc-4.app.ch-geni-net.em
```

Could you please tell me y this error message is coming? 
The below command doesn't solve the problem

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r) /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build

OS: root@pc-4:/home# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise
root@pc-4:/home#
```

It is running on emulab.net virtual PC.

Could you please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you will not have the package if you didn't have the package in your list cache. Normally the easiest method is using the meta-packages instead:

```
apt-cache depends linux-headers-generic
linux-headers-generic
  Depends: linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic
  Conflicts: linux-headers-generic:i386
```

Or better yet to install both headers and image from the same version use the `linux generic` package:

```
apt-cache rdepends linux-headers-generic
linux-headers-generic
Reverse Depends:
  linux-generic

apt-cache depends linux-generic
linux-generic
  Depends: linux-image-generic
  Depends: linux-headers-generic
```

So, do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-generic` then reboot the system to get the most updated headers and image for your system.